# SSL error throws when I try do operation

Tags: ogr2ogr

```
ERROR 1: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

This message appears when I  do an operation using the ogr2ogr library using terminal on MacOS, the URL that I am using is local so I don't have an SSL certificate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
ogr2ogr --config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES output.shp http://localhost:8000/yourfile.geojson
```

where `http://localhost:8000/yourfile.geojson` is your local URL

You can look at https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html to see how to set `GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL` variable. It can be alternatively set by using environment variable if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much.